# Joomla Backend Can't Pull Some Records from MariaDB Database

Tags: joomla

Joomla 5,
Database Type mariadb
Database Version 11.1.2-MariaDB

I had inserted some content into #_content via importing an Excel sheet.
I can pull up these inserted records in console or MariaDB client (Navicat) but they don't appear in Joomla backend.
I have rebooted the server, flushed privileges on MariaDB but got no result.
What would be the problem?

Comment: Mariadb is not mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of multiple reasons:

- You are inserting in the wrong database.
- You are inserting in the right database, but the view in the Joomla backend has some conditions on the rows that are not met.

Try doing it the other way: insert rows from the Joomla backend and see if you see them in the database, if you can't, then you are inserting into the wrong database (or even table). If you don't have the option to insert rows in Joomla, then try checking the query (use Joomla's debug feature) in Joomla, copy it, and try to run it directly in the database. Also ensure that the database and the host in the configuration.php file in your Joomla website are pointing to the database that you are working on.